# Specisific User Access Specific Table in One Database OOP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm studying how to access specific user (in one table user) accessing a specific column in one table.

Example: I have one database with 2 tables:

(1) user table :

> username: (admin, cityA)
>
> password: (12345, 12345)

(2)city table

> name: (nameA, nameB, nameC, nameD)
>
> age: (19, 24, 22, 21)
>
> city: (cityA, cityB, cityC, cityA)

If I log in using username "admin", I can access all data in city table, but if I log in using username "cityA", I can only access "cityA", and if I log in using username "cityB", I can only access "cityB"

I didn't know how to access it.. and sorry, I can't say words well because I didn't know how to do it.

this is my opinion

for username "city"

```
    public static function find_by_city($city){
        global $database;
        $the_result_array_city = static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table_city . " WHERE city= $city LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($the_result_array_city) ? array_shift($the_result_array_city) : false;
}
```

for username "admin"

```
public static function find_all_city(){
            return static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table_city . "");
            }
```

and thanks for your patience for my question.

Comment: thanks for your correction :)

Comment: I think add map every user a role and check user's role before executing your functions. More details about role-based permissions, please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control